# Java Scanner.useDelimiter() problem with ""

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have having a problem with Java Scanner.useDelimiter() delimiting "".

I am trying to use the Scanner to read a CSV file.The CSV have 2 column (Name, Description) and the Description field have long paragraphs (with , and .)

I am wondering what delimiter for this case.

Comment: can the description contain new-lines?

Comment: can the description have commas in it?

Comment: thegravytalker: yes, the op states "Description field have long paragraphs (with , and .)"

Answer (score 3):

How about something like

```
Scanner s = new Scanner("name1 lorem, some description\n" +
                        "name2 ipsum, some other, description \n" +
                        "name3 dolor, a third. description\n");

while (s.hasNextLine()) {
    String[] cols = s.nextLine().split(",", 2); // limit to two columns.
    System.out.println("col1: " + cols[0] + ", col2:" + cols[1]);
}
```

Prints:

```
col1: name1 lorem, col2: some description
col1: name2 ipsum, col2: some other, description 
col1: name3 dolor, col2: a third. description
```

---

Alternatively, if you insist on using Scanner all the way, you could do something like

```
Scanner s = new Scanner("name1 lorem, some description\n" +
                        "name2 ipsum, some other, description \n" +
                        "name3 dolor, a third. description\n");

s.useDelimiter(",");

while (s.hasNext())
    System.out.println("col1: " + s.next() + ", col2:" + s.skip(",").nextLine());
```

(Which yields the same output.)

Answer (score 2):

Just use a library for reading/writing csv like [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) and you don't have to reinvent the wheel :)

Comment: That will also take care of quoted quotes and commas within a field and multi-line strings and so on.

Answer (score 1):

If you've only got two columns, separated by a comma, an easy alternative to `Scanner` is to just use `String.substring`:

```
int i = s.indexOf(',');
String name = s.substring(0,i);
String desc = s.substring(i+1);
```